# My post/comment system doesn't display correctly

Tags: php, sql

Im having trouble with my Post and Comment to Post section of code. I am relatively new to coding and I am not even sure if this is even the best way to do this. The code will post, as well as comment correctly, but the problem is that it won't display correctly. What happens is when it displays it will pull the blab in the correct order as well as the comments, but the comments repeat themselves on upon each post.

So for further clarification it looks like this...

- Post 1
- comment 1
- comment 2
- comment 3
- Post 2
- comment 1
- comment 2
- comment 3
- comment 4
- Post 3
- comment 1
- comment 2
- comment 3
- comment 4
- comment 5

The numbers stand for the ids

Here is my code.

```
// ------- MEMBER BLABS OUTPUT CONSTRUCTION ---------

$sql_blabs = mysql_query("SELECT id, mem_id, the_blab, blab_date, blab_type, device, fromid FROM blabbing WHERE mem_id='$id' ORDER BY blab_date DESC LIMIT 30");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_blabs)){

    $blabid = $row["id"];
    $fromid = $row["fromid"];
    $blab_device = $row["device"];

        $sql_comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blab_comments WHERE blab_id='$blabid' ORDER BY id ASC");
        $count_comment = mysql_num_rows($sql_comments);
        if($count_comment > 0){
        while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql_comments)){
            $comment_mem_id = $row2['mem_id'];
            $com_blab_id = $row2['blab_id'];
            $comment_txt = $row2['the_comment'];
            $comment_date = $row2['comment_date'];
            $convertedTime = ($myObject -> convert_datetime($comment_date));
            $whenComment = ($myObject -> makeAgo($convertedTime));
            $sql_comment_user = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM myMembers WHERE id='$comment_mem_id' LIMIT 1");
            while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_comment_user)){
            $firstname = $row3['firstname']; 
            $lastname = $row3['lastname']; 
            $comment_user = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
            }
            $comment_pic = check_pic("members", $comment_mem_id, "40", "profile");
            ///////  Mechanism to Display Real Name Next to Username - real name(username) //////////////////////////
            $DisplayCommentList .='
                <div style="background-color:#e3eaf3; width:auto; height:auto; word-wrap: break-word;">
                <div style="margin-right:10px; margin:8px; width:40px; height:40px; overflow:hidden; display:inline-block;">'.$comment_pic.'</div>
                <div style="float:right; width:390px; margin-bottom:8px; margin-top:3px;">
                    <span class="liteGreyColor textsize9" style="width:auto;">'.$whenComment.' 
                        <a href="profile.php?id=' . $fromid . '"><strong>'.$comment_user.'</strong></a> said via <em>'.$blab_device.'</em>
                    </span><br />'.$comment_txt.'<br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr style="margin:0px; clear:both; margin-left:8px;" />';
        }
        }else{
            $DisplayCommentList = "";
        }

    $uid = $row["mem_id"];
    $the_blab = $row["the_blab"];
    $the_blab = ($activeLinkObject -> makeActiveLink($the_blab));
    $blab_date = $row["blab_date"];
    $convertedTime = ($myObject -> convert_datetime($blab_date));
    $whenBlab = ($myObject -> makeAgo($convertedTime));
    $blab_date = $row["blab_date"];
    $blab_type = $row["blab_type"];
    $blab_pic = check_pic("members", $fromid, "60", "profile");
       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $usersql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM myMembers WHERE id='$fromid' LIMIT 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($usersql)){
            $fromuser = $row["firstname"];
            $fromuserLast = $row["lastname"];
            $fromusername = $fromuser . ' ' . $fromuserLast;
            if(isset($_SESSION['idx'])){

                $blabberDisplayList .= '
                    <table style="background-image:url(images/white_title.png); color:#333; border:#F0F0F0 1px solid; border-top: 0px; padding-bottom:10px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                        <td width="18%" valign="top"><div id="blab_pic" style="overflow:hidden; width:60px; margin:10px 0px 10px 10px;">' . $blab_pic . '</div></td>
                        <td width="82%" valign="top" style="line-height:1.5em; padding-top:7px;">
                        <span id="myTable" class="liteGreyColor textsize9">' . $whenBlab . ' <a href="profile.php?id=' . $fromid . '"><strong>' . $fromusername . '</strong></a> said via <em>' . $blab_device . '</em></span><br />
                         ' . $the_blab . '
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td width="18%" valign="top"></td>
                        <td width="82%" style="line-height:1.5em; padding-right:15px; background-color:#e3eaf3;" valign="top">
                        '.$DisplayCommentList.'
                        <div id="new_comment'.$blabid.'" style="display:none;">

                        </div>
                        <textarea id="Comment'.$blabid.'" style="width:99%; margin-top:8px; margin-left:8px;" rows="1"></textarea><br />
                        <input style="color:#666; float:right; background-color:transparent; border:0px; margin-left:8px; margin-right:8px;" type="submit" value="comment" onclick="javascript:SendComment(\''.$blabid.'\');" />
                        </td>
                        </tr></table>';

}}}
// ------- END MEMBER BLABS OUTPUT CONSTRUCTION ---------
```

Comment: Page slow much? Suggest you lookup JOIN http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mysql+join

Comment: Actually, I believe joins are not always faster.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, I have thought about it and done a "small" amount of research on Joins, I am just not sure that I quite understand them very well, but I will look more into it. Thanks! Of course right now I am trying to find a solution for this problem, but I really will look into using Joins a bit more.

Comment: @stefgosselin you believe wrong then, with proper indexes 5 query's can be as fast as one, querying the db on each iteration of a 3 Tier while loop when just getting a first n last name is horrid

Comment: Hmm, good to know! Like I said, I'm new at this...

Comment: @Lawrence I think I may of not been clear, I did try to convey that multiple queries can (often) be faster than one multi-join query. Performance wise it usually does not matter much on a small scale, but on bigger applications one often de-normalizes tables and de-constructs queries and other such optimising techniques that seem counter-intuitive at first glance but are really full of common sense once you understand what is causing the bottlenecks in your application stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to place the comment query into a function. While looping through the blabs, it would subsequently loop through "all" of the comments each time it passed over. I got it going now :). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your problem is, but I smell something wrong with the initialisation  of your variables. Rather ... the lack of initialisation! ;o)

It is good practice, *especially* when you loop through a data set that you initialize your variables before using them.

One problem you can have, for example, in your condition `if($count_comment > 0)`, there is obvious need of variable initialisation.  Say you have an iteration where  $count_comment > 0, goes through the loop, sets all the `comment` data, then first thing outside the loop hits `$comment_pic = check_pic("members", $comment_mem_id, "40", "profile");`.

First time, works ok. Second time, let's say user 2 has no comments. Get to `if($count_comment > 0)`, does not go through the loop, goes straight to `$comment_pic = check_pic("members", $comment_mem_id, "40", "profile");` ... can you see the problem, friend? Your comment values are still the same from your first iteration.

In this example, just adding  `$comment_mem_id = "";` first thing in the while it is used in would fix the issue.

Good-luck!

**UPDATE: I may of misread the whiles in there, but basically the idea is the same:  you should initialise your variables, lest you will run into hard to track bugs.

Comment: They are not in the example, but all of my variables are initialized at the top of the page, I just double checked to make sure. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes. Debug the code, slap a few var_dump() in there or echo's and print_r's, use krumo ( http://krumo.sourceforge.net/ ) if you want prettier messages.  Use an ide that has debugger built-in ie: php-edit, zend ide, kommodo, ... or just good old xdebug client straight in apache.

Comment: I am still stuck on this thing, anything else. Through some dumps in there and everything seems to come out ok, except that when a blab and its comments are called, all its comments as well as the preceeding comments form the previous blab are called too.